# Android: How to add a view inside a view programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I want to do something like this:

```
View v1= new View(this);
v1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pic1);

View v2 = new View(this);
v2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pic2);

v1.addView(v2);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;
rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
rl.addView(v1,params);
```

I know the code is wrong. It just show how I want to do.

Some websides said that viewGroup may help me to achieve this.

I had tried but never can v2 be shown on the screen.

Does someone can tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: you answered your question by yourself: only ViewGroup can addView()

Comment: However, when I add VIewGroup into relativeLayout, v2 cannot be shown on the screen. This is the main purpose of this question.

Comment: what is your onLayout method? see other ViewGroup.onLayout implementations

Comment: I am using the the onLayout code of android webside and it work!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Views cannot contain other Views. It simply doesn't work this way in Android.

If you want to place a View inside a different View, the containing View must extend the ViewGroup class.

There are several classes that can help you achieve this:

1. LinearLayout - if you want your views to be aligned vertically or horizontally.
2. RelativeLayout - if you want your views to be positioned relative to each-other and/or the container
3. There a many more.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you mean that use *Layout to achieve this concept?
I never though it and should try via this way.

Comment: Yes. If a view needs to hold other views, it should be ViewGroup extending view, like LinearLayout or RelativeLayout.

Comment: Thanks, I would try to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks ok but the problem might be that you create a View with no params in a relativelayout. Also I don't know if you can create a View object think it have to be TextView, ImageView or something like that :)